# Статический сайт на Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Предположим, есть страница index.htm. Как сделать так, чтобы при переходе на http://example.appspot.com/index.htm или при переходе на http://example.appspot.com этот index.html отобразился в браузере?

Answer (score 2):

К обработчикам в app.yaml нужно добавить подобный код

```
- url: /  static_files: path/index.htm  upload: path/index.htm- url: /(.+)  static_files: path/\1  upload: path/(.+)
```

Подробнее: [обработчики статических файлов](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers).